# How can i program 'previous bars open price' to appear in an alert message

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

currently i have an alert set to arrive in my discord server, it is triggered on an engulfing candle. what i want to achieve, is when this alert triggers, is to deliver the previous bars open price as a number/price.

Currently i have got as far as: { "content" : "{SELL - price = {{open[1]}}" } as the json code for the alert message inside tradingview alerts. Prior i have '{{close}}' instead of {{open[1]}} as close call delivered the closing price successfully.

is this something i could call directly from the alert settings (the previous bars open price) or would i need to code an alert message in the indicator / strategy script to call for a message?

Any insights are most helpful.